# Why does the JList replace the items instead of adding?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jframe, jlist

ive made a code that adds items from a *Arraylist* into a *JList*. The probelm is that when i press the button to add the items to the *jlist* it replaces the 1st one when i add the 2nd one, and so on.

i dont know where the issue lies in the code, so i hope to get help to pin point the issue and get some help with some solutions.

here is a version of the code in question:

```
String GetTitle = ItemTitleField.getText();//getting the text from the textfield.
String GetDesc = ItemDescField.getText();
String CreatedItem = "Title: " +GetTitle+"   " +"Description: " + GetDesc;//putting the two together
ES.Item.add(CreatedItem);//adds the textfield strings into the arraylist

final DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel(); 
ItemList.setModel(dlm);

for (int i = 0; i < ES.Item.size();){// a loop to put the items from the arraylist into the Jlist.

   dlm.addElement(i+ ". "+ ES.Item.get(i));
   i++;
}
```

if any more code is needed, or if the question is unclear. just tell me. - TheBigChung

All the core that interacts with the arraylist:
Class: 1

```
EbaySite ES = new EbaySite(); 
String GetTitle = ItemTitleField.getText();
String GetDesc = ItemDescField.getText(); 
String CreatedItem = "Title: " +GetTitle+" " +"Description: " + 
GetDesc; ES.Item.add(CreatedItem); 
final DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel(); 
 ItemList.setModel(dlm); 
for (int i = 0; i < ES.Item.size();){ 
dlm.addElement(i+ ". "+ ES.Item.get(i)); i++;
 }
```

Code: 2

```
EbaySite_startpage ESP = new EbaySite_startpage(); 
final ArrayList<String> Item = new ArrayList<String>(); 
public void ItemsArray(){ 
Item.add("Test");
 }
```

Comment: Is it possible that you are replacing `ES.Item` with a new list?  What happens if you define `ES.Item` as `final`?

Comment: Where in the code should i write "final". Itried writing it at row; 4, 7 and 11 just before ES.Item but then i get the message: "illegal start expression".

Comment: In the `ES` class.  Something like:  `final List<String> Item`.

Comment: Didn´t work. I put the "final" infornt of the arraylist; "final ArrayList<String> Item = new ArrayList<String>();". Nothing seems to have changed.

Comment: What does your JList look like?  Multiple copies of the same string?  Or always just a single list item?

Comment: My arraylist has one Item from the jump named "test", which doesnt show up either btw. And then i have the method that should create as many items as the user whants to create when you press a button. my list looks like this:    `final ArrayList<String> Item = new ArrayList<String>();     public void ItemsArray(){
    Item.add("Test");
    }   ` and the code above that creates  more items, and thats it.

Comment: There is not enough information to determine the cause of the problem.  Please include all lines of code which create or alter `ES.Item`.

Comment: That's very hard to read.  Edit your question, using the ‘edit’ link beneath the shaded keyword rectangles at the bottom your question, and add the code to the question itself.

Comment: I have now put in the all the code that alter or interacts with the ES.Item arraylist. Sry hope its easier now.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: We need a lot more.  Obviously your `Item` list isn’t what you expected, so we need to see every line of code that contains the five characters `Item.` (notice the period), and the methods that contain those lines.

Comment: but that is all the code that contains the code ´Item´. the rest of the code is from the jform which cant be altered with. I don´t understand.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1831987/vgr, @VGR , you there still?

Comment: `EbaySite ES = new EbaySite();` creates a new EbaySite object, with an empty list.  Then you add one item to it.  That is why your JList’s model only contains one item.  Create `ES` only once, outside of your ActionListener, and store it in a private field.